# Why do I keep getting null object reference exceptions in Android?

Tags: java, android, exception, nullreferenceexception, gettext

Every time I use getText() on an EditText or getValue() on a NumberPicker, this exception (or a close variation) is thrown. I've managed to make one app work with the getText() method, but I can't for the life of me discern what the difference is between that successful bit of code and all the other failures. Any suggestions? I've included the code for my non-working number picker.

```
package com.example.daniel.forjoe;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        NumberPicker redVal = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.RedPicker);
        NumberPicker greenVal = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.GreenPicker);
        NumberPicker blueVal = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.BluePicker);

        SetBounds(redVal);
        SetBounds(greenVal);
        SetBounds(blueVal);
    }

    public void ChangeColor (View v) {
        TextView smiles = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.smilez);

        NumberPicker redVal = (NumberPicker) v.findViewById(R.id.RedPicker);
        NumberPicker greenVal = (NumberPicker) v.findViewById(R.id.GreenPicker);
        NumberPicker blueVal = (NumberPicker) v.findViewById(R.id.BluePicker);

        int red = redVal.getValue();
        int green = greenVal.getValue();
        int blue = blueVal.getValue();

        int bgIntColor = argb(255, red, green, blue);

        smiles.setBackgroundColor(bgIntColor);

        setContentView(R.layout.color_page);
    }

    public void SwitchBack (View v) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public int argb (int alpha, int red, int green, int blue) {
        return Color.argb(alpha, red, green, blue);
    }

    public NumberPicker SetBounds (NumberPicker np) {
        np.setMaxValue(255);
        np.setMinValue(0);
        return np;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: We need your log to offer any real help.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely issue is in your `ChangeColor` method (I cannot tell for sure without layout xml). Here you are actually trying to locate child views of `View v` passed to the method instead of root content view.

```
public void ChangeColor (View v) {
    TextView smiles = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.smilez);

    NumberPicker redVal = (NumberPicker) v.findViewById(R.id.RedPicker);
    NumberPicker greenVal = (NumberPicker) v.findViewById(R.id.GreenPicker);
    NumberPicker blueVal = (NumberPicker) v.findViewById(R.id.BluePicker);
...
```

You should replace above code with

```
public void ChangeColor (View v) {
    TextView smiles = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.smilez);

    NumberPicker redVal = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.RedPicker);
    NumberPicker greenVal = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.GreenPicker);
    NumberPicker blueVal = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.BluePicker);
...
```

Comment: Better yet-  get the views once (at the start) and store references to them in variables so you don't have to do an O(n) tree walk each time.